# VML background image

Tags: email, outlook, vml

I have a new challenge, which I haven't seen posted or answered here....

I have an image that needs to appear in the top-right corner of an email in Outlook, but that image is treated like a background image - the main content of the email is floated over it. The image file is NOT the width of the email. It's about 15% of the width of the email and perhaps 20% the height.

The email body must be 640px wide, height is variable. The image is 203px wide and 432px tall.

I'm using VML to display the background image in Outlook. The image is set to be the background image of a `<td>` tag, and that tag contains a number of additional tables that provide the email body (hence the variable height). The image should appear only once at the top right of the td.

Would coordorigin and coordposition be a valid approach to keep the image to a single location, or would it negatively impact the td containing the rest of the email body?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the bare minimum you need to achieve what you are asking for:

```
<!-- main containing table -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <!-- main body table -->
      <table class="w320" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="position:relative;">
        <tr>
          <td style="position:relative;>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]-->
          <v:image src="...yourimagehere.jpg" style="width:203px;height:432px;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:-1;" />
          <![endif]-->

          Your email here
```

Bear in mind that using a negative z-index on VML objects when using a background colour on the body of your email will result in the VML object displaying behind the bgcolor

VML allows a lot more styles than your typical HMTL rendered in the word processor, take full advantage where you can.

I can't actually remember if "right" works for position in Outlook. if not just use left:397px; instead.

Hope this helps